# Spread Data accross all nodes in HIVE HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying a usecase where when i create a table in Hive and load/insert data to the table, It only stores the data in any of the underlying Datanode managed by Namenode as per HDFS file system.

In my usecase, I have to spread my data accross all exisitng DataNodes in the cluster automatically when we load the data into Hive table. Let say if have 3 nodes and the table data should spread across these nodes. I am not taking in count of replication here instead the actual data should spread accross all existing nodes.

Is there any simple way we can acheive this in Hive with any settings?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand your question. You want the data to be partitioned into three partitions in Hive, and each node houses one partition? This is all under-the-hood stuff and generally the best advice is to leave this stuff up to Hadoop. You can always experiment with block sizes and make sure your Hive table is partitioned.

Comment: "only stores data in any"... Um, no, the data blocks are split and distributed to multiple nodes, even with only one replica, assuming your data format actually is splitable and larger than the filesystem blocks size. If it isn't, then you shouldn't be using hdfs/Hive